# How to render a json file located on different port in symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, json, angularjs, symfony

I'm new to symfony2 and I'm in a bit of a pickle.
I have setup localhost using wamp server and assigned ports: 
80 (default) to symfony: mylocal/app_dev.php/test
8080 for public folder : mylocal:8080/css/*.css, mylocal:8080/js/*.js, etc.

Now, I have a json file (mylocal:8080/json/test.json - {"name":"test"}) which i want to access in my symfony2 controller so that I can perform simple AJAX get calls by accessing url: '/test'.

Any help on how to do that? How can I access that json file in my controller so that I can perform Ajax.

PS: I'm using Angularjs to control my application and mylocal is alias for localhost. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use $http service and you need CORS headers set on 8080.

Comment: I dont know how to do that. Is that (CORS headers) something coming from Symfony2 controller?

Comment: your request to mylocal:8080/json/test.json should return CORS headers. to do so you should configure server or app if serving json from an app.

more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in this code :

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
       $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        //insert in database
       $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent(json_encode($data));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: but how am I accessing the file which is in 8080 port?